# How do I know when a button is released?

Tags: c#

So I'm making a simple program where I need to know if a button is pressed, and I need to know when a button is released after it's been released. I need to be able to complete an action when it's released

Comment: Do you mean an on-screen button, or a keyboard button? Is this WPF or WinForms?

Answer (score 3):

Winforms/WPF: MouseUp

WebForms: onkeyup

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear if you're working with webforms or winforms, but .NET provides event handlers for pretty much any event that could happen.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button_events%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)'s a listing of the events Buttons handle.

The one you're looking for is 'Click'.  This method will be fired whenever the user clicks on the button.

If you need to do something when the user pushes down on the mouse and again when he releases, Button isn't right for you.  Many other objects implement the 'OnMouseDown' and 'OnMouseUp' events, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about a winform and a keyboard press use the `KeyUp` event ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup.aspx ) If you're talking about a mouse click use `MouseUp` ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseup(v=vs.71).aspx ).

Comment: Could also be 'Click' for a mouse clicking a button.